# Whitespace is not preserved correctly in <pre>

Tags: html, css, node.js

I'm running maintenance on a chat app I'm making, but the whitespace doesn't seem to be preserved correctly. My first attempt at fixing it was to wrap it in a <pre> element, which fixed the whitespace issue partially, but when I put in this:

```
test

sentence
```

I only got this in return:

```
test
sentence
```

My second attempt was to add CSS styling, by changing `white-space: pre;` to `white-space: pre-wrap;` which still didn't work.

I'm stumped, I can't find a way to fix it, either.

HTML:

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#1d5ea9" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- include('partials/header.ejs'); -%>
    <div class="titlecon">
      <h1>
        Arcs <span style="font-weight: 200">Slate</span>&nbsp;<span
          style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 15px"
          >v3.0.0-indev11</span
        >
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontainer">
      <div id="appendto"></div>
      <div id="chatform" style='display: flex; align-items: center;'>
        <textarea
          placeholder="This field supports Markdown!! 2000 character limit."
          id="chat_input"
          type="text"
          maxlength="2000"
        ></textarea>
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" accept="image/*" style="display: none;" />
<button class="chatfiles">Browse...</button>
        <button id="chatsubmit">>></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/arrive.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      let notifMuted, loggedIn;
      let alreadyConnected = false,
isSlowed = false;

      if (localStorage.getItem("notifMuted") == undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("notifMuted", false);
        notifMuted = false;
      } else {
        notifMuted = localStorage.getItem("notifMuted");
      }

      let User;
      if (localStorage.getItem("user") == undefined) {
        window.location = "/edit";
      } else {
        User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      }

      if (localStorage.getItem("readrules") == undefined) {
        window.location = "/rules";
      }

      // Call this shit FedEx
      class MailSystemClass {
        constructor() {
          // this is where id put my shared mailing resources...
          // ...if i had any!!!
        }
      }

      class MailmanClass extends MailSystemClass {
        constructor(pkgtype, message, user, room, attaachment) {
          super();
          this.pkgtype = pkgtype;
          switch (this.pkgtype) {
            case "message":
              this.message = message;
              //this.attachment = attachment;
              this.room = room;

              this.pkg = {
                message: this.message,
                sent: new Date(Date.now()),
                room: this.room,
                user: user,
                //attachment: attachment
              };
              break;
            case "join":
              this.room = room;
              this.preroom = message;

              this.pkg = {
                room: this.room,
                preroom: this.preroom,
                user: user,
              };
              room = this.room;
              break;
            case "command":
              this.callback = message;
              this.type = user;

              this.pkg = {
                callback: this.callback,
                type: this.type,
              };
              break;
          }
        }

        send() {
          switch (this.pkgtype) {
            case "message":
              socket.emit("messages", this.pkg);
              break;
            case "join":
              socket.emit("join", this.pkg);
              break;
            case "command":
              socket.emit("command", this.pkg);
              break;
          }
        }
      }

      let has_focus;

      class MailboxClass extends MailSystemClass {
        constructor() {
          super();
        }

        append(pkg) {
          $("#appendto").append(pkg);
          document.getElementById("appendto").scrollTo({
            top: document.getElementById("appendto").scrollHeight,
            left: 0,
            behavior: "smooth",
          });
        }

        sendNotif(pkg) {
          if (
            Notification.permission == "granted" &&
            !notifMuted == true &&
            !has_focus == true
          ) {
            new Notification(pkg.user.disName + "@" + pkg.user.ugn, {
              body: pkg.message,
            });
          }
        }
      }

      const socket = io();
      const MailSystem = new MailSystemClass();
      const Mailbox = new MailboxClass();

      let room = "::GENERAL";

      socket.on("connect", function (data) {
        if (!alreadyConnected) {
          let Mailman = new MailmanClass("join", "", User, room);
          if (!(User.disName == undefined)) {
            Mailman.send();
            alreadyConnected = !alreadyConnected;
          }
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("chatsubmit").onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let message = $("#chat_input").val();

        if (!message.replace(/\s/g, "").length) {
          /* empty */
        } else {
          document.getElementById("chat_input").value = "";

          let Mailman = new MailmanClass("message", message, User, room);
          Mailman.send();
        }
      };

      $("#chat_input").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
          e.preventDefault();

          let message = $("#chat_input").val();

          if (!message.replace(/\s/g, "").length) {
            /* empty */
          } else {
            document.getElementById("chat_input").value = "";

            let Mailman = new MailmanClass("message", message, User, room);
            Mailman.send();
          }
        }
      });

      socket.on("broad", function (data) {
        Mailbox.append(data);
      });

      socket.on("notification", function (data) {
        Mailbox.sendNotif(data);
      });

      document.arrive("#date", function (element) {
        element.textContent = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
      });

      function joinRoomLogic(rtj) {
        if (room == rtj) {
          // user is already in room
        } else {
          let Mailman = new MailmanClass("join", room, User, rtj);
          Mailman.send();
          room = rtj;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
/* HAHAHAH REDESIGN + REWRITE GO BRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter+Tight:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

:root {
  --txtclr: #000;
  --bgclr: #FFF;
  --stclr: #000;
  --mnubtnclr: black;
  --chtsubbg: #FFF;
  --chtinpbg: #ececec;
  --apndbrdr: black;
  --menubg: #c6c6c6;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
  --stclr: #c7c5c5;
  --bgclr: #323333;
  --mnubtnclr: #edebeb;
  --txtclr: whitesmoke;
  --chtsubbg: #575959;
  --chtinpbg: #575959;
  --apndbrdr: white;
  --menubg: #212121;
}
}

html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Inter Tight", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: var(--bgclr);
  color: var(--txtclr)
}

pre {
  font-family: 'Inter Tight', sans-serif;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.leftmenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: var(--menubg);
  width: 48px;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#appendto {
  border: 1px solid var(--apndbrdr);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(85% - 10%);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1.5px 7px;
}

#message {
  background: #1d5ea9;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 3.5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#chatform {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 3px;
  gap: 3px;
}

#chat_input {
  background: var(--chtinpbg);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: calc(100% - 33px);
  margin-right: 3px;
  height: 40px;
  color: var(--txtclr);
  font-family: "Inter Tight", sans-serif;
}

#chatsubmit, .chatfiles {
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--txtclr);
  background: var(--chtsubbg);
}

a {
  text-decoration: wavy underline;
  color: inherit;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.menubutton {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: var(--mnubtnclr);
}

.statusmsg {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--stclr);
}

.hr {
  background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.pfplink {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: color 1.5s;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.pfplink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: color 0.5s;
  color: #1d5ea9;
}
```

Node.JS:

```js
// Imports
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const striptags = require("striptags");
const compression = require("compression");

const markdown = require("markdown-it")({
  html: true,
  linkify: true,
  typographer: true,
  breaks: true,
})
  .use(require("markdown-it-emoji")) // there
  .use(require("markdown-it-abbr")) // are
  .use(require("markdown-it-deflist")) // way
  .use(require("markdown-it-footnote")) // too
  .use(require("markdown-it-ins")) // many
  .use(require("markdown-it-sub")) // of
  .use(require("markdown-it-sup")) // these
  .use(require("markdown-it-mark")) // it
  .use(require("markdown-it-anchor")) // looks

// Declarations
let app = express();
let clients = [];
let httpServer = http.createServer(app);
let io = new socketio.Server(httpServer);

/* Routes */
let routes = {
  main: require("./routes/main.js"),
  login: require("./routes/login.js"),
  extras: require("./routes/extras.js"),
};

// Functions
function cleanseMessage(message) {
    return striptags(markdown.render(striptags(message)), [
            'strong',
            'i',
            'em',
            'code',
            'a',
            'div',
            'sub',
            'sup',
            's',
            'abbr',
            'dl',
            'hr',
            'ins',
            'section',
            'ol',
            'li',
            'sup',
            'sub',
            'code',
            'pre',
            'br',
            'h1',
            'h2',
            'h3','h4','h5','h6'
          ])
}

function createMessage(username, message, bio) {
  let cleansedMessage = cleanseMessage(message);
  let formattedUsername = `<span class='pfplink' onclick='window.location = "/profile?user=${username}&bio=${bio}"'>${username}</span>`;
  let formattedDate = `<span style='font-size: small;'> [at <span id='date'></span>]</span>`;
  let formattedMessage = `<div id='message'><pre>${cleansedMessage}</pre></div>`;
  let formattedDiv = `<div style='margin: 10px 0;'><span>${formattedUsername}${formattedDate}</span>${formattedMessage}</div>`;

  return formattedDiv;
}

// Initialization
app.use(compression())
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

/* Routes */
app.use("/", routes.main);
app.use("/", routes.login);
app.use("/", routes.extras);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404);

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('error.ejs', { url: req.url });
    return;
  }

  // respond with json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.json({ error: '404 Not found' });
    return;
  }

  // default to plain-text. send()
  res.type('txt').send('404 Not found');
});

// Socket.io
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  console.log('Client connected...')
  client.join('::GENERAL')

  client.on('join', function(data) {
    if (data.user.disName !== undefined) {
      if (data.preroom !== '') {
        client.leave(data.preroom);
        client.join(data.room);
        client.to(data.room).emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined this chat room.</div>`);
        client.to(data.preroom).emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} left this chat room.</div>`);
        client.emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>You joined ${data.room}.</div>`);
      } else {
        console.log(`${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined.`);
        client.to('::GENERAL').emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined this chat room.</div>`);
        client.emit('broad', "<div class='statusmsg'>You joined the chat room.</div>");
      }
    }
  });

  client.on('connect_error', (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`)
  })

  client.on('messages', (data) => {
    if (data.user.disName !== undefined) {
      const message = createMessage(`${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn}`, data.message, data.user.bio);
      client.emit('broad', message);
      client.to(data.room).emit('notification', data);
      client.to(data.room).emit('broad', message);
    }
  });
})

httpServer.listen(8443, () => {
  console.log("running arcs at localhost:8443");
});
```

Live demo is [here](https://arcs.is-probably.gay/chat)

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, but you might be falling foul of a quirk of the html parser, where initial newlines character inside a `<pre>` are discarded. Try pre-pending a newline character to every `cleansedMessage`.

Comment: As in, changing `<div id='message'><pre>${cleansedMessage}</pre></div>` to `<div id='message'><pre><br>${cleansedMessage}</pre></div>`?

Comment: No. Just a real newline character. Like ASCII 0x0A.

Comment: I changed it to `<div id='message'><pre>\n${cleansedMessage}</pre></div>`, but it still doesn't show the extra lines. Any other ideas? Did I do it wrong?